# Using "with AutomatickeepAliveClientMixen" to save the state of my firstPage.dart and "keepAlive true" at the end of the code but doest save the State

Tags: flutter

I have been given advice to use the AutomaticAliveClientMixen and the wantKeepalive => True to make sure my page states stay alive with all data added and maybe scroll state as well, but happy just with the data preserved.
But not working...
Code:

```
// TODO Implement this library.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tca/navbar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: AddTwoNumbers()));
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddTwoNumbers> createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  List<TextEditingController> roundOneFields = [];
  List<TextEditingController> roundTwoFields = [];
  int roundOneResult = 0;
  int roundTwoResult = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    roundOneFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    roundTwoFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Twin City Bowmen Score Sheet'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(25))),
      ), // This is how you can add an appBar.
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R1 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundOneFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 24,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R2 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundTwoFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      roundOneFields.forEach((e) =>
                          roundOneResult = roundOneResult + int.parse(e.text));
                      roundTwoFields.forEach((e) => roundTwoResult =
                          roundTwoResult + int.parse(e.text.toString()));
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text("Back"),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Navbar())))
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult Total = ${roundOneResult + roundTwoResult}",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

I tried these few lines of code in the class and the end of the class.

```
class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {



  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```